# can't create table `info` (foreign key constraint is incorrectly formated

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm using `navicat` software.

I was created `users` table.

my columns :

```
id  - fname
```

`id` is `primary` and `auto increment`.

now, I want to create `info` table :

```
CREATE TABLE `info` (
`user_id`  int NOT NULL ,
`fname`  varchar(255) NULL ,
PRIMARY KEY (`user_id`),
FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `users` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE
)
;
```

but I got this error :

```
can't create table `info` (foreign key constraint is incorrectly formated)
```

my users table sql:

```
CREATE TABLE `users` (
  `id` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `username` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Comment: Here's a new and innovative idea: [Check the documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html) to learn the proper syntax for adding a foreign key constraint. Wow! I should remember that for future reference!

Comment: I'm learning about `navicat ` software and my db is as a test.

Comment: Should users.id having int datatype?

Comment: @ Rahul Patel yeah .

Comment: added `users` table sql.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two mistakes in your SQL scripts.

1) While creating `USERS` table please create index for `id` field. If no index has been created no foreign key will created for it in another table.

```
CREATE TABLE `users` (
  `id` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `username` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
   INDEX `id_index` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

2) While creating `info` table `user_id` field should have same datatype `int(10) UNSIGNED` as it is in `users.id` field.

```
CREATE TABLE `info` (
`user_id` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
`fname`  varchar(255) NULL ,
PRIMARY KEY (`user_id`),
INDEX `fk_INFO_idx` (`user_id`),
FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `users` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Answer (score 0):

in this statement, try delete the quotes on 'users' cause it's a table name,

*FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES **`users**` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE*